# How to reload 2nd page when i click the button in 1st page in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

## My Doubt is

In my browser i opened two windows (i.e., two tabs in browser). In one window (WINDOW1) table data is there. In another window (WINDOW2) one button is there. If I click the button in another window (WINDOW2), one window page (WINDOW1) will reload. How to do that?

**Is it understandable??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you. You can use [Broadcast Channel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) to send message to all page in the same channel.

Page 1 (Send message to page2)

```
<button onclick="postMsg();">Test</button>
<script>
    var bc = new BroadcastChannel('abc'); // connect to 'abc' channel
    function postMsg() {
        // send message to everyone in channel
        // you can send anything you want
        bc.postMessage('heyreload'); 
    }
</script>
```

Page 2 (Receive message from page1)

```
<script>
    var bc = new BroadcastChannel('abc'); // must same channel as page1
    bc.onmessage = function (ev) { // event occurs when receive message
        // do anything you want in here
        // example reload page
        if (ev.data == 'heyreload') {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Mark this answer as "accepted" if this worked for you ;)